# Delete picked image using SAF

Tags: android

In my app, I want to copy and delete picked image. I tried to use Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT but it does not seem to work.

Could you advise, what kind of flag should I use to delete picked image using SAF?

Here is my code which is not working:

// this function opens for multiple images

```
private fun openForImages(){
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.setType("image/*")
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), OPEN_IMAFGES_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
```

Here onActivityResult I cannot get writing authority which I need to delete photo.

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == OPEN_IMAFGES_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            val clipData = data?.clipData ?: return
            for(i in 0 until clipData.itemCount){
                val mUri = clipData.getItemAt(i).uri
                val docFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, mUri)
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: ${docFile?.name}, canWrite=${docFile?.canWrite()}") // canWrite returns false
                docFile?.delete() // this is not working
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: include your code please

Comment: You do not need any flag if you delete the file directly in onActivityResult().

Comment: I included source code now. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the answer!!! If anyone needs:

```
  val intent = Intent()
        intent.setType("image/*")
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION or
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
        }
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)

        startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            OPEN_IMAFGES_REQUEST_CODE
        )
```

in onActivityResult

```
val clipData = data?.clipData
if (clipData != null)
    for (i in 0 until clipData.itemCount) {
       val mUri = clipData.getItemAt(i).uri
       deleteFromUri(mUri)
     }
}
```